# Passing values to html dropdown

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How can I pass values from my query controller to my html view dropdown list. I just want to use a query to see values from dropdown and from my query I have columns id and names the id will be hidden on dropdown and names are only visible because I have a target that might be needing the unique id for my updating.

Currently here my pseudo code to read my controller:

```
<html>
    <select id="names" onclick="getNames()" style="width:200px; height:35px; margin-left:700px">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Names</option>
    </select>
</html>

<script>
    function getNames() {
        //alert("here");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/showData',
            type: 'GET',

            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                var row = '';
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    row += '<option style="display:none;" value=' + item.id + '> ' + item.id + '</option>';
                        + '<option value=' + item.name + '> ' + item.name + '</option>';

                });
                $('#names').html(row); // override previous results
            },

            error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown.toString());
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

I already build my query to my controller that returns json:

```
public ActionResult showData()
    {
        //Load mgr list table from MySql
        List<Details> listItems = new List<Details>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = "SELECT id, concat(f_name,', ',l_name) as names FROM tblInfo";
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            listItems.Add(new empDetails
                            {            
                                id = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["id"]),                        
                                name = sdr["names"].ToString(),                                   
                            });
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: '{0}'", e);
                        }
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return Json(listItems, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Why not using `SelectList` or `List<SelectListItem>` on GET method before passing to view? You're adding 2 option tags for both `id` and `name` while you should just pass them as single option tag: `'<option value=' + item.id + '> ' + item.name + '</option>'`. Also the `<select>` element selector seems wrong - it should be `$('#names')`.

Comment: I just refer it to my previous code to pass data to my tables that's why I use pseudo code here in dropdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues on the AJAX call:

1) The `<select>` selector uses class name instead of element name (at the time of original version). Use `$('#names')` instead.

2) You're creating option list for both `id` and `name` separately. You can use `value` attribute set to the `id` and the text set as `name`.

Therefore, the AJAX callback to populate `<select>` element should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Home/showData',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var ddl = $('#names');
        ddl.empty(); // clear existing values
        $.each(data, function (i, item) {
            ddl.append($('<option>', {
               value: item.id,
               text: item.name
            }, '</option>'))
        });
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(errorThrown.toString());
    }
});
```

However, if the dropdown should be populated from page load (i.e. after calling `return View()` from controller side), you should use `List<SelectListItem>` for option lists and `DropDownListFor` to create `<select>` element, and pass the option list to either `ViewBag` or a `List<SelectListItem>` viewmodel property:

**Controller action**

```
ViewBag.ListItems = listItems.Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.name, Value = x.id }).ToList();
```

**View**

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.names, ViewBag.ListItems as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { style="width:200px; height:35px; margin-left:700px" })
```

Comment: it looks good, I can see values from my drop down but it seems like it has repeating values, looks like every time I click the drop down it will append the values continuously. not sure if because my event on component is onclick

Comment: I forgot to mention you should use `$('#names').empty()` before appending new option list - edited on AJAX call part.

Comment: cool. but there still a bug. e.g if I select value from row 2 or 3 or 4. it will return back the value to index0 or row 0

Comment: Are you want to tell that those `<select>` elements are inside table cells? If that's the case, you should use `class` selector for all `<select>` elements - not `id` selector.

Comment: I mean every time I will select row index it will always display row index 0 or the first value on the list in dropdown

Comment: Probably that occurred because you're using `onclick` trigger to populate it. Try using other triggers like `onchange`, e.g. `$('#names').change(...).trigger('change')`, or use `$(document).ready()` event to trigger on page load.

Comment: I replace onclick to onchange on html element but not familiar which I need to change on script. could you give exact solution on that again?

Comment: Assumed you have `onchange="getNames()"`, you should replace current AJAX call with provided in answer and retry. If you want to populate the `<select>` on page load, `<body onload="getNames()">` should be used and make sure that your AJAX wrapped inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: it's working now very appreciate it, I am just struggling trying to learn things in this platform

Comment: I put the script on onload but how can I show initial value for my dropdown e.g Select Names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183283/discussion-between-tetsuya-yamamoto-and-rock-n-roll).